# CKEditor IE8 issue

Tags: internet-explorer, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Has anyone experienced this problem with CKEditor and IE8?

Basiclally, when the content included a nested p tag, you cant edit the content.

i.e.

```
<div>
<p>This content cannot be changed in IE8</p>
</div>
```

Anyone have a fix?

UPDATED with an example

Sorry for pulling this back up, The problem is caused when the div has a width OR a height either via the content.css or inline. Such as:

```
<div style="width:400px">
<p>This content cannot be changed in IE8</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you post a link to a live example?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro your problem by inserting the HTML you gave into [CKEditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) and it worked fine. Something else is going on in your case.

Do you have your own CSS applied?

Answer (score 0):

I can indeed reproduce it now. Not nice! :)

In fact, the div *is* editable, it's just very hard to get the cursor into it. It's possible by clicking on the div, then outside it to its right (at least I managed to get into the field that way). The content itself is editable.

This has been filed as a [**Bug in CKEditor**](http://dev.fckeditor.net/ticket/4682). It has a [**patch**](http://dev.fckeditor.net/attachment/ticket/4682/4682.patch) worth checking out:

> With this patch the behavior is the same than FCKeditor, so elements with layout are editable after clicking and waiting a little. This can help to fix #4910 as now it will be possible to position the hidden div (at least I hope so)

Let us know whether the patch works!

Answer (score 0):

same happened for me using IE8/7... in my case the html was more like this:

```
<div class="width50 floatright">
<p>Some text you can't edit in IE</p>
</div>
<p>This text you can edit in IE</p>
```

css (external file) as follows:

```
div.width50{
    width:50%;
}
.floatright{
    float:right;
}
```

Applying the above patch does work, however there's a couple more hoops to jump through in order to get it working. You need to re-package the files.

Read this:

[recompressing ckeditor files after edits](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2009/12/recompressing-ckeditorjs-to-fit-your.html)

worked for me...